# Read. Check. Write. A Broken Python script

Tags: python

I am developing a word game, and for this game, I needed a list of words. Sadly, this list was *so* long that I just had to refine it (this list of words can be found on any Mac at **/usr/share/dict/**).

To refine it, I decided to use my own Python scripts. I already wrote a script before that removes all words that start with capital letters (thus removing names of places, etc.), and it worked. This is it:

```
with open("/Users/me/Desktop/oldwords.txt", "r") as text:
    with open("/Users/me/Desktop/newwords.txt", "w") as towriteto:
        for word in text:
            if word[0]==word[0].lower():
                towriteto.write(word)
```

Then, I decided to refine it even further; I decided that I would delete all words that are not in the pyenchant module English dictionary. This opperation's code is very similar to the previous one's code. This is my code:

```
import enchant
with open("/Users/me/Desktop/newwords.txt", "r") as text:
    with open("/Users/me/Desktop/words.txt", "w") as towriteto:
        d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
        for word in text:
            if d.check(word):
                towriteto.write(word)
```

Sadly, this did not write anything to the "towriteto" file, and after some debugging, I found that

```
d.check(word) -> False
```

It always returned false. However, when I checked words separately, real words returned True, and fake words returned False as they should.

I have no idea what is wrong with my second script. The file locations are correct and the pyenchant installation had no issues.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the file look like? Is it one word per line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the input file format but if there is only one word per line, try to remove the end-of-line character of `word` before to call `d.check(word)`:

```
word = word.rstrip()
```

Comment: or just `strip()` but yeah +1 ... you beat me to it :P

Comment: @user76691 Let's take the example of the word `"hello\n"`. If my hypothesis is correct, in the first script you only test `"h" == "h".lower()` which is `True` so the word is written in `towriteto`. In the second script, you test `d.check("hello\n")` which probable returns `False` as the dictionary must contains `"hello"` but not `"hello\n"` so the word is not written in `towriteto`.

Comment: This always raises an error: ** (process:3135): CRITICAL **: enchant_dict_check: assertion `len' failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/enchant/__init__.py", line 641, in check
    self._raise_error()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/enchant/__init__.py", line 612, in _raise_error
    raise eclass(default)
enchant.errors.Error: Unspecified Error

Comment: Did you try to print words too see where the problem is?

Comment: @clemtoy Nothing can be printed because the error is caught at the first word. I believe that it has to do with the rstrip() function. I sadly do not get much info from the error so I am honestly lost.